# From Ant to Maven

Tags: maven, ant

I am trying to mavenize an Ant project (web application) with Eclipse.

To do so I tried the "easy" way :

- Right click on the project → Configure → Convert to Maven
- Then I added the dependencies (the pom file looks fine and I don't have dependencies issues)

The build (clean install) is successful and generates a war file but I can't deploy it in Tomcat.
I noticed that there were differences between the war file generated by the Ant project (38 000 lines) and the one generated from the Maven project (27 000 lines). It seems that some parts are missing (for example the css part of the code).

I was thinking maybe this is because the project doesn't have a "real" Maven structure as it has the Ant one.

[image: Picture of the Ant project structure]

So I tried to create a Maven project in Eclipse and then add the files to it (`src` goes to `src/main/java`, etc.). Regarding this I am not sure where to put the `web` folder.
I tried different ways but nothing works.

How should I proceed?

Comment: AFAIK web stuff has to be in `/src/main/webapp` by default.

Comment: The first you have to change is the directory structure. I always recommend to change the structure first in the Ant build and get it working and afterwards migrate to Maven so it's easier to compare the results...

Answer (score 0):

The standard location for webapps in maven is `src/main/webapp`. Just move the contents of your `web` folder there, and you should be fine.